# Optional parameter only when the generic type is not provided

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to make a function like this:

```
function TT<O>(arg: O){}
```

I want `arg` to be required only when `O` is provided, ex:

```
TT() // OK!
TT<string>("hello") // OK!
TT<string>() // Typescript error, not OK, arg is required.
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: ```function TT<O>(arg?: O){}```?

Comment: this makes `arg` always optional, I want `arg` to only be optional when the function `TT` is called without specifying the generic type parameter, ex: `TT<string>() // NO, arg is required`

Comment: What should happen if you skip the `<0>` parameter like `TT('hello')`?

Comment: @Konrad, simple. typescript should infer the type automatically based on arg. in this case "hello" is a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with function overloads by providing separate overload which doesn't accept parameters:

```
function func(): any;
function func<O>(arg: O): any;
function func<O>(arg?: O) {}

// Usages
func(); // -> works
func<string>(); // -> error, missing arg
func<number>('yolo'); // -> error, incorrect type of parameter
func<string>('yolo'); // -> works
func('yolo'); // -> works, type parameter inferred from argument
```

Comment: Why is the first call signature generic?

Comment: Otherwise TS will yell at you that this signature isn't compatible with function implementation

Comment: You could try something like `function func<undefined>(): any;` but this will break second test case and you'll need to update second overload to exclude `undefined` from type parameter which isn't very convenient without negated types

Comment: Hmm, just checked again and it works fine without type parameter. I'll update the answer